# MYSQL Error code 1248 Every derived table must have it's own alias

Tags: mysql, alias

> **MYSQL Error code 1248 Every derived table must have it's own alias**

```
select supplier_id, supplier_name, strong_answers from 
(select campaign_suppliers.id supplier_id, campaign_suppliers.supplier_name supplier_name, 
count(case when supplier_answers.binary_answer is not null 
or supplier_answers.value_answer is not null then 1 end) strong_answers 
from supplier_answers join campaign_suppliers on (supplier_answers.supplier_id = campaign_suppliers.id) 
where supplier_answers.campaign_id = 1 group by campaign_suppliers.id, campaign_suppliers.supplier_name 
having count(case when supplier_answers.binary_answer is not null 
or supplier_answers.value_answer is not null then 1 end) >=  
(select count(distinct supplier_answers.question_index) from supplier_answers where campaign_id = 1)) 
where strong_answers >= (select count(distinct supplier_answers.question_index) from supplier_answers where campaign_id = 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need  a table name alias for the `from  (   ...  ) t` see `// <----` symbol below

```
select t.supplier_id, t.supplier_name, t.strong_answers from (
    select campaign_suppliers.id supplier_id, campaign_suppliers.supplier_name supplier_name, 
    count(case when supplier_answers.binary_answer is not null 
      or supplier_answers.value_answer is not null then 1 end) strong_answers 
from supplier_answers join campaign_suppliers on (supplier_answers.supplier_id = campaign_suppliers.id) 
where supplier_answers.campaign_id = 1 group by campaign_suppliers.id, campaign_suppliers.supplier_name 
having count(case when supplier_answers.binary_answer is not null 
or supplier_answers.value_answer is not null then 1 end) >=  
(select count(distinct supplier_answers.question_index) 
        from supplier_answers where campaign_id = 1)) t //<----  here you need  a table name eg: t
where t.strong_answers >= (select count(distinct supplier_answers.question_index) from supplier_answers where campaign_id = 1)
```